# Minimization of sum of squares

Tags: optimization

I'm having trouble figuring out how to minimize the expression:

$$(k_1 + 2)^2 + (k_2 + 2)^2 + \cdots + (k_m + 2)^2$$

given that $k_1 + k_2 + \dots + k_m = 17$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: [Cauchy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) gives you that $$((k_1+2)^2+(k_2+2)^2+...+(k_m+2)^2)(1^2+1^2+...+1^2)\geq ((k_1+2)\cdot1+(k_2+2)\cdot1+...+(k_m+2)\cdot 1)^2=(17+2m)^2$$ and that the equality happens when $k_1+2=k_2+2=...=k_m+2$. In that case we get $(k_1+2)^2+(k_2+2)^2+...+(k_m+2)^2=(17+2m)^2/m$.

Answer (score 4):

Show that if $k_1 \neq k_2$ you can decrease the sum by making both the average.  Then argue that this means all the $k$s are equal.

Comment: This is known as Sturm's Method

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\min \{ \sum_i (k_i+2)^2 | \sum_i k_i = 17 \}$ has the same solutions as $\min \{ \sum_i (k_i+2)^2 | \sum_i k_i = 17 , \sum_i (k_i+2)^2  \le 19^2\}$ and the latter has a compact feasible set so has a solution.

Lagrange gives $2 (k_i+2) + \lambda = 0$ hence all the $k_i$ are the same and so $k_i = {17 \over m}$.

**Alternative**: (Not really.)

Let $x_i=k_i+2$, then the problem is $\min\{ \sum_i x_i^2 | \sum_i x_i = 17-2m \}$, that is the nearest point to the origin in the plane $\sum_i x_i = 17-2m$ which is $x_i = {17 \over m} -2$, and so $k_i = { 17 \over m}$.

**Another one**: (A more complicated way of writing Ross' answer.)

Note that the problem is convex and furthermore, if $k$ satisfied the constraint so does $Pk$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix, and $f(k) = f(Pk)$, where $f$
is the cost.
 Since the problem is convex, we have
$f({1 \over |\cal P|} \sum_{ P \in {\cal P}} Pk ) \le {1 \over |\cal P|} \sum_{ P \in {\cal P}} f(Pk) = f(k) $ and it is intuitively clear that ${1 \over |\cal P|} \sum_{ P \in {\cal P}} Pk = (\sum_i k_i) (1,1,...,1)^T$, so we can restrict the search to the set of vectors that all have the same component. The answer follows.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** By Cauchy-Schwarz

$$\left( k_1+2+k_2+2+...+k_m+2 \right)^2 \leq \left( (k_1 + 2)^2 + (k_2 + 2)^2 + ... + (k_m + 2)^2\right) \left(1+1+...+1 \right) $$

Equality occurs when 
$$\frac{k_1+2}{1}=\frac{k_2+2}{1}=...=\frac{k_m+2}{1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The map $x \mapsto (x+2)^2$  has second derivative of 2 and hence is striclty convex.

$\mathbf k \succeq \frac{17}{m}\mathbf 1$ so with $f: \mathbf x \mapsto \big \Vert\mathbf x + 2\mathbf 1\big \Vert_2^2$ you have  $f\big(\mathbf k\big) \geq f\big(\frac{17}{m}\mathbf 1\big)$ with equality iff $\mathbf k =\frac{17}{m}\mathbf 1$.  An equivalent finish without using majorization is to observe the result follows by Jensen's Inequality by a nearly identical convexity argument.